# Traefik with nip.io

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm trying to expose some applications using traefik and nip.io

My docker-compose file looks as the following

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7-alpine
    command: --web --docker --docker.domain=app.test --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

  whoami:
    image: tons/whoami-go
    labels:
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.127.0.0.1.nip.io"
```

But I can't reach my service

```
$ curl -vvv whoami.127.0.0.1.nip.io
```

The above returns 404 and the complete verbose output is

```
$ curl -vvv whoami.127.0.0.1.nip.io
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* Connected to whoami.127.0.0.1.nip.io (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: whoami.127.0.0.1.nip.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Mon, 19 Apr 2021 12:07:29 GMT
< Content-Length: 19
< 
404 page not found
* Connection #0 to host whoami.127.0.0.1.nip.io left intact
```

It works just fine when I do

```
$ curl -vvv -H "Host: whoami.127.0.0.1.nip.io" localhost
```

And the complete output is very similar

```
$ curl -vvv -H "Host: whoami.127.0.0.1.nip.io" localhost
*   Trying ::1:80...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: whoami.127.0.0.1.nip.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 12
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Date: Mon, 19 Apr 2021 12:12:13 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
49d197f2d4ae⏎
```

Notably the host header is sent correctly with both requests.

I have the same issue using jwilder/nginx-proxy but I have no problem when I'm using nip.io with Kubernetes ingress regardless of using Traefik or Nginx.

Anyone got a clue about what's wrong?

UPDATE: This works on my friends Mac and in an ubuntu VM, but not on my Fedora box

Answer (score 0):

You can us the majic domain by configuring HostRegexp.
eg : - "traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=HostRegexp(`app1.{ip:.*}.nip.io`)"
Full details https://traefik.me